# Python + Pandas JSON Url Call via api : Cannot save resuls as CSV index problem scalar values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

Trying to do a simple script to save as csv. My python Version is  3.8.3 and I am using window 10.
I am trying to use the tool pandas : https://pandas.pydata.org

I am trying to get data results from the URL `https://barcode.monster/api/3061990141101`. I  installed Pandas to convert the JSON file to csv. There is an "index" problem. None of the answers I found worked.

> Value error if using all scalar values, you must pass an index.

I looked all over Google and forums, and tried adding  `"index_col=0"` , also `"index=false"`.

Below is my python script :

```
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://barcode.monster/api/3061990141101") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

    print(data)
with open('data.json', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f_input:
    df = pd.read_json(f_input, index_col=0)    
    df.to_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

I'm sure this is obvious for any Python dev, I'm just learning from scratch. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of solving this issue. If you're going to use open a text file, then you'll need to convert the string to json. Try using `json.load(f)`. Doing so, you can call `DataFrame`. You will then need to either set the index to the first item or wrap the json data in a json object.

For example:

```
with open('data.json', "r") as f_input:
    text = f_input.read()
    jsonData = json.loads(text)
    df = pd.DataFrame(jsonData, index=[0])  
    df.to_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Or:

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'data': data})
    df.to_csv('test.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```